# How to call a function every 5 second in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I want to call my ViewModel's function every 5 seconds. What is the best way to do that in Jetpack Compose?

Comment: Have a mutable state of Int and update that value in every 5 second, once value will change then it will re-compose automatically..

Comment: Or, have the every-five-seconds logic be part of the viewmodel itself.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It depends when you want this behaviour to start and end.

This will run as long as your composable remains in the composition:

```
LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
    while(true) {
        vm.someMethod()
        delay(5000)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Precisely what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
 LaunchedEffect(state.showCards) {
        Log.d("gameScreen", "launcheffect: state.showCards")
        if(state.showCards){
            repeat(5){
                Log.d("gameScreen", "count: ${it+1}")
                delay(1000)
            }
            viewModel.hideCards()
        }

    }
```

This above code is for the case if you want to do something on some event(on button click) and after 5 second trigger a function to do something else with a count down